# apply dask map_overlap on dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I am wondering if I can apply dask map_overlap on dataframe partitions or should I convert them to array and then use this method.

The main purpose of using map_overlap is to perform some grouping on a sorted dask in order to reshape each partition

Comment: `I am wondering if I can apply dask map_overlap on dataframe partitions`. Yes you can

Comment: Thx @NickBecker